# Describe SKPhysicsContact object (attributes and methods)

Tags: ios, swift, skphysicscontact

I know (I think at least) that when two sprites collide, the didBeginContact method defined in the SKPhysicsConstactDelegate will be called with SKPhysicsContact as a parameter.

What are the methods and attributes associated with the SKPhysicsContact object though?

I can't seem to find any information online about this other than "An SKPhysicsContact object is created automatically by Sprite Kit to describe a contact between two physical bodies" from https://developer.apple.com/.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what exactly a SKPhysicsContact object is. Does anyone know of any links that describe it?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the framework reference. You get the two bodies that collide, the collision point, and others. But you have to make sure you set up your two objects properly to do that. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContact/